# React-native-maps and Geolocation not getting location properly

Tags: android, ios, react-native, geolocation, react-native-maps

I am very new to learning React Native and would appreciate any help that can be provided with my code. I am currently working off of tutorials and have been stuck for hours.  Hopefully this is enough info to get some help.  Thanks in advance!

**My goal**

I am trying to do three things (in this order):

1. Get the user's current location
2. Fetch the items data from an API (example outlined below). It should be noted that eventually the contents of the fetch will be dependent on the user's current location.
3. Parse the items data to create markers and a unique list of categories and place those on the map with the user's current location at center to begin with.

I am looking to be able to watch the user's location and move and update the map accordingly.  I also don't want to show the map until all of the markers are in place.

Here are my react versions: react-native-cli: 2.0.1 react-native: 0.63.2

**My Bugs**

I am using both the Android Studio emulator as well as the Xcode emulator and am currently running into the following problems:

1. The iOS emulator on Xcode renders fine the first time, but on subsequent refreshes I see 1 or two of my 5 markers missing.
2. On Android, the map loads perfectly then appears to immediately redraw itself and center on the Googleplex in California instead of the user's current location.
   [Emulator location is set to London, UK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKPTf.png)

I suspect I might have some race condition with fetching the items and current location before the map renders but I can't be sure.

**My Code**

//my API response structure

```
{
"id": "96845",
"title": "Item_title_goes_here",
"image": "https://someURL/image.JPG",
"stories": 46,
"lat": some_lat_number,
"lon": some_lon_number,
"category": "category_name",
"description": "long_description"
},
```

```
//ajax.js 

export default {
    async fetchInitialItems() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(apiHost + '/api/v1/items/');
            const responseJson = await response.json();
            return responseJson;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    },
    async fetchItemDetail(itemId) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(apiHost + '/api/items/' + itemId);
            const responseJson = await response.json();
            return responseJson;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    },
};
```

```
//ExploreScreen.js (my map component)

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    Animated,
    Dimensions,
    TouchableOpacity,
    PermissionsAndroid,
    ScrollView,
    Platform,
    StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {
    PROVIDER_GOOGLE,
    Marker,
    Callout,
    Polygon,
} from 'react-native-maps';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import { mapDarkStyle, mapStandardStyle } from '../model/mapData';
import ajax from '../utils/ajax';
import MapCarousel from './MapCarousel';

import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import Fontisto from 'react-native-vector-icons/Fontisto';

import StarRating from '../components/StarRating';

/**
|--------------------------------------------------
| Variables
|--------------------------------------------------
*/
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const SCREEN_HEIGHT = height;
const SCREEN_WIDTH = width;
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0422;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;
const darkTheme = false;


/**
|--------------------------------------------------
| Component
|--------------------------------------------------
*/
class ExploreScreen extends React.Component {
    /****** Props & States ******/

    state = {
        region: {
            latitude: 0,
            longitude: 0,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        },
        items: [],
        markers: [],
        categories: [],
        currentMapRegion: null,
    };

    /****** Functions ******/

    ///when carousel item selected
    onCarouselItemSelected() {
        alert('carousel item selected');
    }

    //when the carousel in scrolled
    onCarouselIndexChange(itemID) {
        const item = this.state.items.find(item => item.id == itemID);
        const marker = this.state.markers.find(marker => marker.id == itemID);
        const coordinates = { lat: item.lat, lon: item.lon };

        this.goToLocation(coordinates);
    }

    //get current position
    getLocation(that) {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            //get the current location
            position => {
                const region = {
                    latitude: parseFloat(position.coords.latitude),
                    longitude: parseFloat(position.coords.longitude),
                    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
                };
                that.setState({ region });
            },
            error => alert(error.message),
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000 },
        );
        //get location on location change
        that.watchID = Geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
            const currentRegion = {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
            };
            this.setState({ region: currentRegion });
        });
    }
    //move map to a lat/lon
    goToLocation(coordinates) {
        if (this.map) {
            this.map.animateToRegion({
                latitude: coordinates.lat,
                longitude: coordinates.lon,
                latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
            });
        }
    }

    //when the region changes for the map
    onRegionChangeComplete(region) {
        //I dont know what to do here 
    }

    //move map to center of current location
    gotToCenter() {
        if (this.map) {
            this.map.animateToRegion({
                latitude: this.state.region.latitude,
                longitude: this.state.region.longitude,
                latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
            });
        }
    }
    //map the categories store in the state
    mapCategories = () => {
        const uniqueCategories = [];
        this.state.items.map(item => {
            if (uniqueCategories.indexOf(item.category) === -1) {
                uniqueCategories.push(item.category);
            }
        });
        this.setState({ categories: uniqueCategories });
    };

    //map the items to markers and store in the state
    mapMarkers = () => {
        const markers = this.state.items.map(item => (
            <Marker
                key={item.id}
                coordinate={{ latitude: item.lat, longitude: item.lon }}
                image={require('../assets/map_marker.png')}
                tracksViewChanges={false}
                title={item.title}
                description={item.description}
            />
        ));
        this.setState({ markers: markers });
    };

    /****** Lifecycle Functions ******/
    async componentDidMount() {
        var that = this;
        //Checking for the permission just after component loaded
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            //for ios
            this.getLocation(that);
        } else {
            //for android
            async function requestLocationPermission() {
                try {
                    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        {
                            title: 'Location Access Required',
                            message: 'This App needs to Access your location',
                        },
                    );
                    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                        //To Check, If Permission is granted
                        that.getLocation(that);
                    } else {
                        alert('Permission Denied');
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    alert('err', err);
                    console.warn(err);
                }
            }
            requestLocationPermission();
        }

        //get location on location change
        that.watchID = Geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
            const currentRegion = {
                latitude: parseFloat(position.coords.latitude),
                longitude: parseFloat(position.coords.longitude),
                latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
            };

            this.setState({ region: currentRegion });
        });

        console.log(this.state.region);

        const items = await ajax.fetchInitialItems();
        this.setState({ items });
        this.mapMarkers();
        this.mapCategories();
    }

    componentWillUnmount = () => {
        Geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
    };

    render() {
        const lat = this.state.region.latitude;
        const lon = this.state.region.longitude;

        if (this.state.items && lat && lon) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <MapView
                        ref={map => {
                            this.map = map;
                        }}
                        onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete.bind(this)}
                        toolbarEnabled={false}
                        showsMyLocationButton={false}
                        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                        style={styles.map}
                        customMapStyle={darkTheme ? mapDarkStyle : mapStandardStyle}
                        showsUserLocation={true}
                        followsUserLocation={true}
                        region={this.state.region}>
                        {this.state.markers}
                    </MapView>
                    {/* center button */}
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={this.gotToCenter.bind(this)}
                        style={styles.centerButtonContainer}>
                        <Ionicons name="md-locate" size={20} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <View style={styles.carousel}>
                        <MapCarousel
                            data={this.state.items}
                            onPressItem={() => {
                                this.onCarouselItemSelected.bind(this);
                            }}
                            onUpdateLocation={this.onCarouselIndexChange.bind(this)}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.header}>Loading...</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
}

/**
|--------------------------------------------------
| Styles
|--------------------------------------------------
*/
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    map: {
        height: '100%',
    },
    carousel: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 25,
    },
    header: {
        fontSize: 50,
    },
    //character name
    name: {
        fontSize: 15,
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
    //character image
    image: {
        width: 170,
        height: 80,
    },
    //center button
    centerButtonContainer: {
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 260,
        right: 10,
        borderColor: '#191919',
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderRadius: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#d2d2d2',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 9,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.48,
        shadowRadius: 11.95,
        elevation: 18,
        opacity: 0.9,
    },
});

export default ExploreScreen;
```

Comment: First clean a bit the code, you have two watchPosition(you really need this feature?). The problem in ios can be that you are setState items but you don't think about that call is async so when u start mapMarkers state.items can be empty, in same way in your render state.items is always present because its [] so when lat and lon is there it will be render. Also you can rid onRegionChangeComplete. Update me with the results and the changes.

Comment: I'm not sure on how to address the async issue. Do I make the calls synchronous? If so, how?

Comment: You can just pass items directly if this.state.items is null.

Comment: I am unsure of how to proceed here.  I have made these calls synchronous but I am not seeing anything on the map now.

Comment: what u got when mapMarkers is rendered console log this.state.items and in render method console.log this.state.markers